# iOS: Launch Safari with URL automatically

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

some basic questions for a very basic app:

For the first time when the app runs, the user is presented with a screen where an ID (number) has to be selected. This ID is then embedded in a URL that is used when launching Safari as the user is pushes a Start button. The ID is stored in the user preferences.

The second time the app is launched, I just want to read out the ID from user preferences and launch `Safari`, without the user seeing the ID screen or pushing any buttons.

The first scenario I got working by reading out the ID in `viewDidLoad` etc.
For the second scenario I'm pretty much clueless. Where should that code be placed. Is it technically possible? Would Apple accept this?

Comment: Try it in `AppDelegate`. But I suspect you will still have _switching app_ animation.

Comment: If all you app does is launch safari with some set parameters, then there is a big, let's say almost certain, chance that you app will be reject. Since apps that under rule **2.12** : `Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected`

Comment: Rather than launching safari why dont you use UIWebView component for loading you webpage.Using UIWebView will maintain user experience and user wont notice any app switches + Appstore wont reject it.

Comment: @2intor using a webview does not decrease the chance of a rejection. Since you are still just wrapping a website the chances of a rejection are just as great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. And why Apple would not accept this? Just use this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

url - your composed URL with user ID.